# Boats/ferries/cargos from Dakar to Cape Verde islands?

Tags: ferries, senegal, cape-verde

I'm wondering if it is possible to catch a boat from Senegal mainland to Cape Verde and how much/long it would cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that there are no regular ferries.  In 2009, Graham Hughes (first dude to visit all countries in the world without using a plane) had to pony up €3,500 to [charter a seriously dodgy fishing boat](http://www.theodysseyexpedition.com/2009/day-150-voodoo-economics) for the trip, and was [thrown into jail](http://www.theodysseyexpedition.com/2009/day-154-you-came-in-that-thing) on arrival as an illegal immigrant.